# How can I promise chain a redux / sagas dispatch in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

In my component, I have:

```
export default connect(
  (state) => ({
    autocomplete: state.autocomplete,
    search: state.search,
  }),
  (dispatch) => ({
    onSearch: (location) => (q) => dispatch(actions.push(getUrlWithQS(location, { qs: { q } }))),
    onAutocomplete: (q) => dispatch(actions.autocomplete({ q })),
  }),
  (stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) => ({
    ...stateProps,
    ...dispatchProps,
    ...ownProps,
    onSearch: dispatchProps.onSearch(ownProps.location),
  })
)(Home)
```

I also have:

```
  doSearch(location) {
    console.log(this.props.onSearch);
    this.props.onSearch(location)
  }
```

Is it possible for me to make `onSearch` a promise so I can know when the dispatch is complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The mental model is that a saga is like a separate thread in your
> application that's solely responsible for side effects.
>
> `redux-saga` provides some helper effects wrapping internal  functions(takeLatest, takeEvery, etc.) to spawn tasks when some specific actions are dispatched to the Store.

To handle side effects, `redux-saga` allows you to **dispatch other actions to handle error or success cases**(here is your promise like behavior).

To update your component after an action,   [componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) allows you to detect state modifications and do something afterward.

In a saga asynchronous action, you can use `put` or `call` to get your desired side effects.

Relevent exemple from the [documentation](https://redux-saga.github.io/redux-saga/docs/basics/UsingSagaHelpers.html) :

```
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects'

export function* fetchData(action) {
   let url = action.payload.url
   try {
      const data = yield call(Api.fetchUser, url)
      yield put({type: "FETCH_SUCCEEDED", data})
   } catch (error) {
      yield put({type: "FETCH_FAILED", error})
   }
}
```

To launch the above task on each `FETCH_REQUESTED` action :

```
import { takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects'

function* watchFetchData() {
  yield takeEvery('FETCH_REQUESTED', fetchData)
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `componentWillReceiveProps` because it will become deprecated https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops